# How to use applescript to close upload dialog window from chromedriver instance?

Tags: java, macos, selenium, applescript, selenide

I have a selenium test (selenide to be precise) where the scenario requires a file upload.
The element to which I'm uploading the file is **a hidden input field** which is located at the end of DOM;

`<input type="file" style="height: 0; width: 0; visibility: hidden;" tabindex="-1" accept="*">`

and appears only after clicking on the area where the file is supposed to be "drag&dropped" or loaded from the system;

`<a class="browse" ref="fileBrowse" href="#">select files...</a>`

that means I am unable to use any method I've known until now without the need to click the element first - e.g., sendKeys, uploadFile, uploadFromClassPath, etc. However, the moment I click the element, a dialog window appears. After loading the file, the window won't close and I have yet to find a robust solution to close that window.

[Situation how the dialog window looks within the macOS and chrome setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmbFr.png)

I am using macOS and chrome, which means I cannot use "autoIT", and I was not able to run "sikuliX" either to create a simple screenshot script.

I was able, however, to scramble up an applescript using Automator which worked fine provided we omit the web driver's instance existence. Meaning; if I run the script from the console, setting the website exactly as the automated test would find it - it works... Unfortunately, it does not work once the test instantiates and runs within the webdriver.

I have two questions I hope someone with more experience could answer:

**1) How to make the applescript use the webdriver's instance and not the regular chrome window - should this be solved somehow, it's a pretty neat solution**

**2) Any other idea on how to close the upload dialog window?**

The applescript

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- Click “Google Chrome” in the Dock.
    delay 6.006100
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click UI Element \"Google Chrome\" of list 1 of application process \"Dock\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )
    return input

    -- Click the ÒCancelÓ button.
    delay 3.763318
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
    set uiScript to "click UI Element \"Cancel\" of sheet 1 of window \"PowerFLOW portal - Google Chrome\" of application process \"Chrome\""
    my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    return input
end run

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

the code used to run the script within the test

```
      try {
        new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/the/script").start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Besides trying to use the applescript, I've tried "java robot class" but I wasn't able to close the dialog window.

Using the snippet below, the uncommented part escapes the entire chrome window (the window goes "grey"/inactive) and not the dialog window, which honestly surprised me, as I have thought the dialog window was the main working window at that moment.

The part that is commented works, but as you can imagine, it is useless, should the test be run on any other machine as the coordinates are specific to my machine only.

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        //robot.mouseMove(906, 526);
        //robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        //robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

The method itself looks just about like this

```
$$x("#ElementsCollection")
        .findBy("text1")
        .scrollIntoView(true)
        .find(byXpath("#xpath")).val("text2")
        .find(byXpath("#xpath") //this is the location of the <a> element mentioned above that needs to be clicked in order for <input type file> element to appear
        .click();

$x("//input[@type=\"file\"]").sendKeys("/path/to/the/uploadedFile");
```

Comment: When I learned AppleScript I moved away from selenium. Trying on Big Sur, I've no problems accessing either the regular Chrome window versus the one launched by selenium web driver. How are you not able to access the selenium window, does the window not exist when accessed via AS or are the UI elements (buttons) not accessible for click?

Comment: I wasn't able to anyhow differentiate between a regular Chrome window and the one selenium driver controls. I ran the webdriver, opened UI Inspector on Mac, viewed the IDs and names of the buttons I wanted to click on running the applescript, did the same for regular Chrome session and compared those two. The results were identical, hence the reason I was unable to successfully run the command. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: I see, so you needed to differentiate between the two types of browser windows. I would check the difference in the UI elements, IIRC selenium driver-launched window has got less UI components (not sure which UI elements are missing) perhaps that can be used as a distinguishing factor.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the original complexity on the way to achieve the goal is

> the file is a hidden input field

> and appears only after clicking on the area where the file is supposed to be "drag&dropped" or loaded from the system;

I.e. – the hidden file. Correct me if am wrong:)

But this should not be the problem, because the Selenium WebDriver's sendKeys command works with hidden elements of input tag with type=file. So just simple  sendKeys should pass. The Selenide's uploadFromClassPath command is based on the original sendKeys - so it should pass too.

Here is a simple test that shows that uploading file does not depend on visibility of input element:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.hidden;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.text;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;

public class TheInternetTest {
    @Test
    void fileUpload() {
        // GIVEN
        open("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload");
        executeJavaScript(
                "document.getElementById('file-upload').style.display = 'none'"
        );
        $("#file-upload").shouldBe(hidden);

        // WHEN
        $("#file-upload").uploadFromClasspath("temp.txt");
        $("#file-submit").click();

        // THEN
        $("#uploaded-files").shouldHave(text("temp.txt"));
    }
}
```

Check the full working project with this code here: https://github.com/yashaka/selenide-file-upload-demo/blob/main/src/test/java/TheInternetTest.java

P.S.
The common best practice when writing Web UI Tests is "find the simple way to reach the goal instead of the best way in context of real user simulation". That's why we try to bypass all windows that are out of control for application under test. So my recommendation would be - forget apple script, and work with the input file directly through selenium webdriver.